# Item select is not happening when using data from json

Tags: javascript, html

Here I am getting some problem in HTML code. When I assigning value in table from some data.json then onclick event on the tabel is not working where as when
I am defining the table values ion code itself the click event and select event is happening.

Here is my code.

```
SomeCombo = function(args) {
    debugger;
    var divID = args.divID;
     var div = document.getElementById(divID);
     var input = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onclick="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">';
        var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">'+
          '<table id="myTable">'+ '<tr class="header"></tr>' + '<tr><td></td></tr>'+ '</table>';
      /*'<table id="myTable">'+
        '<tr class="header"></tr>'+ 
        '<tr><td>Germany</td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td>UK</td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td>Germany</td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td>Canada</td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td>Italy</td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td>UK</td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td>France</td></tr>'+
      '</table>'*/
      div.innerHTML = myTable;

 function foo(callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', "data.json",true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                // trigger your callback function
                callback(httpRequest.responseText);
            }
        };
        httpRequest.send();
    }

    foo(function(data) {
      debugger;
        var jsonc = JSON.parse(data);
        var new_opt="";
        for(i=0;i<jsonc.length;i++)
        {
            new_opt+='<tr><td>'+jsonc[i]['VALUE']+'</td></tr>';
        }
        document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML =new_opt;
    });

 myFunction = function() {
  debugger;
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
//  Here is onclick even in code.
document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.header)').forEach(function(_tr){
  debugger;
    _tr.addEventListener('click',function(){
              document.getElementById('myInput').value += " "+  this.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
    });
});

}
```

The commented line of code is directly defined in table.

Data which is coming from json is lie :

```
"[
    {
        "ID" : 0,
        "VALUE" : "United State"
    },{
        "ID"  : 1,
        "VALUE" : "United Kingdom"
    },{
        "ID"  : 2,
        "VALUE" : "Afghanistan"
    },{
        "ID"  : 3,
        "VALUE" : "Aland Islands"
    },{
        "ID"  : 4,
        "VALUE" : "Albania"
    }
]"
```

Note : Data is appearing in table by json if I comment .

This below code is working as I want but when I am loading dynamic data things are not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 30%;
  height : 30%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: none;
  margin-top:-12px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
  width : 10%;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  order-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#myInput:focus + #myTable{
  display: block;
}

#myTable:hover{
 display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header"></tr> 
  <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Canada</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Italy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>France</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.header)').forEach(function(_tr){
    _tr.addEventListener('click',function(){
              document.getElementById('myInput').value += " "+  this.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does `data` look like before you `JSON.parse` it

Comment: @JaromandaX  I updated my questions.

Comment: do you get any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: when/how is `SomeCombo` executed?

Comment: @JaromandaX I update my question with the code is working. But for dynamic it is not working.

Comment: hmmm, looks like you'll populate `#myTable` AFTER you `_tr.addEventListener('click'` - because asynchronous AJAX is asynchronous - in other words, you're attempting to attach event handlers before the DOM has been dynamically updated

Comment: ok... Ya I am understand this... can you please help me to fix..

Comment: put the event handler stuff inside the callback just after you set the innerHTML of `#myTable`

Comment: Wow.. Works like a charm. Can you make this as a answer. So I can accept that. Also one css is not applying here. `#myTable` any comment for that.

Comment: which one isn't?

Comment: @JaromandaX placed my code in callback and selection is working. Mean the actual question is working by your comment. `#myTable` css is not applying... well I am checking that